# wp_list_categories : how do I sort by ID when IDs are not sequential

Tags: categories

Trying to display a category by an odd sequence and have the following:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&include=4,5,6,7,8,9,10,72,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41'); ?>
```

notice after ID #10 it jumps to ID #72.  How can I code this better?

Note:  Names are not alphabetical and numbers are not sequential, so just need to display IDs #4 to #10, #72, #11 to #41 listed in that order.

Respectfully,
jw

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<ul>
<?php
wp_list_categories('order_by=ID&title_li=&include=4,5,6,7,8,9,10');
wp_list_categories('order_by=ID&title_li=$include=72');
wp_list_categories('order_by=ID&title_li=&include=11,12,13,14,15,16,17, 18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41');
?>
</ul>
```

Just listing them in order for the include arg won't help you since that only goes into the WHERE clause, not into the ORDER BY clause of the SQL query.

Comment: Well, I feel stupid.  I thought I had tried that a few hours ago, thank you wyrfel, it certainly worked.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but you may be interested in the [My Category](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-category-order/) plugin.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it but I am more interested in a programmatic solution this time.  :)

Comment: I just tried the plugin and it didn't work...I also tried the Category Order plugin and that was not what I needed either.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, if i understood a little bit (of your question) right...

```
$args_include = array(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,72,11,12,13,14,15,16,17, 18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41)';
$args_include = sort( $args_include, SORT_NUMERIC);

wp_list_categories( 'orderby=id&include='.$args_include );
```

...but i guess i haven't. So, what have the *includes* in common? And what "Note: Names are not alphabetical and numbers are not sequential" does that mean? I can't see any names, only IDs.

Comment: Thank you for your time kaiser.  What I meant is I can't seem to order by title since the title names would not provide the correct sequence.  I tried wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&include=4...72...41'); which placed 72 last.  So, I was hoping there was a way to order by a range, like [4-10,72,11-41] or something similar.